# nx - knex - Cannot find module '@nx-created-lib-project/something'

Tags: shared-libraries, knex.js, monorepo, nrwl-nx

It seem I cannot seem to grok NX.

I have 2 packages in a [newly integrated NX project](https://nx.dev/getting-started/integrated-repo-tutorial).

We have @ici/shared and @ici/project.

@ici/project is a knex migration project, where the migration files use imports of @ici/shared.

Whenever I try to run the knex migration command (knex migrate:up) it says following error:

`Cannot find module '@ici/shared'`

It seems I'm missing the context, which is available in my paths variable in my tsconfig where knex can resolve @ici/shared. I have already tried to include it in a [NX run command](https://nx.dev/packages/nx/executors/run-commands) with the same error as result. And the [nx run-script command](https://nx.dev/packages/nx/executors/run-script#nx:run-script) with the same error.

Anybody has any suggestions to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer while writing this question.

It seems [Knex has an open issue where it doesn't read the tsconfig](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/4698) resulting in failing to resolve local paths.
You can fix this with adding following to the top of the knexfile.ts:

```
import 'tsconfig-paths/register';
```

Also ts-node [has the same issue](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node/issues/219)